# How does du compute human-readable sizes?

Tags: disk-usage

Here's a concrete example, using actual data.  If I run `du` as shown below on `/path/to/some/dir` I get:

```
% du -s --bytes /path/to/some/dir
4218593783204   /path/to/some/dir
```

I want to get that size in "human-readable" units, such as KB, MB, GB, etc, where

```
1 KB = 2 ** 10 B
1 MB = 2 ** 20 B
1 GB = 2 ** 30 B
1 TB = 2 ** 40 B
1 PB = 2 ** 50 B
1 EB = 2 ** 60 B
```

In the case of this example, the desired human-readable unit is 1 TB, so, according to the convention set out above, the original 4218593783204 bytes translates to

```
% printf -- "%f TB\n" $(( 4218593783204.0 / 2 ** 40 ))
3.836789 TB
```

So I'm looking for an output from `du` along the lines of `3.8T`.  So far so good.

The problem is that I cannot come up with in invocation of `du` that will report a human-readable size anywhere near 3.8T.  Instead, I get this:

```
% du -sh /path/to/some/dir
5.3T    /path/to/some/dir
% du -s --si /path/to/some/dir
5.8T    /path/to/some/dir
% du -s --block-size=$(( 2 ** 40 )) /path/to/some/dir
6   /path/to/some/dir
```

(Mind you, the last desperate attempt above, using `--block-size`, is grossly inadequate, even if it worked, since it requires that I know ahead of time which of KB, MB, GB, etc. I want.)

I am mystified by these results.  The manual for `du` says the following:

```
       -h, --human-readable
              print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

       --si   like -h, but use powers of 1000 not 1024
```

...which does not help me at all understand what's going on.

**Q:** Can someone explain to me how `du` arrives at the numbers 5.3T, 5.8T, and 6 for the last three commands above?

Comment: How _many_ files does your directory contain? `--bytes` is equivalent of `--apparent-size --block-size=1`.  Could you re-run you other commands with the `--apparent-size` option enabled?

Comment: @Kusalanda: around 60 million.